# laravel livewire error Undefined variable $_instance

Tags: ckeditor, laravel-livewire

I have a form with which I add posts. I want to integrate CKEDITOR, to manipulate the content in textarea. to initialize the editor, I use the following code :

```
 <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js">
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#post_content'))
            .then(editor=>{
                editor.model.document.on('change:data',(e)=>{
                    @this('post_content').set('post_content', e.editor.getData());
                });
            })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.error(error);
        });
    </script>
```

When I submit form, I get the following error :

**> Undefined variable $_instance**

here's my form, I mention that without CKEDITOR, it works

```
 <form wire:submit.prevent="addNewPost()" method="post" id="createPostForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="" class="form-label">
                                Titlu
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="post_title" name="post_title" class="form-control" placeholder="Titlul articolului" value="{{old('post_title')}}">
                            <span class=" text-danger ">@error('post_title') {{$message}}@enderror</span>
                        </div>
                        <div wire:ignore class="mb-3">
                            <label for="" class="form-label">
                                Continutul articolului
                            </label>
                            <textarea  wire:model="post_content"class="ckeditor form-control" id="post_content" name="post_content" cols="30" rows="10" >{{$post_content}}</textarea>
                            <span class="text-danger">@error('post_content'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <div class="form-label">
                                Categoria articolului
                            </div>
                            <select wire:model="post_category" name="post_category" id="" class="form-select">
                                <option value="">--Nu ati ales nimic--</option>
                                @foreach (\App\Models\SubCategory::all() as $category)
                                    <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->subcategory_name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            <span class="text-danger">@error('post_category'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <div class="form-label">
                                Imaginea articolului
                            </div>
                            <input type="file" wire:model="post_image" name="post_image" class="form-control">
                            <span class="text-danger ">@error('post_image'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="image-holder mb-2" style="max-width: 250px;">
                            <img src="" alt="" class="img-thumbnail" id="image-previewer" data-ijabo-default-img=''>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" id="sub" class="btn btn-primary">Salveaza</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And this is my component Posts.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Post;
use Livewire\Component;
Use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use App\Traits\ShowToastrTrait;

class Posts extends Component
{
    use withFileUploads;
    use showToastrTrait;

    public $post_title, $post_content,  $post_category,  $post_image;
    protected $rules = [
        'post_title' => 'required|unique:posts,post_title|max:255',
        'post_content' => 'required',
        'post_image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'post_category' => 'required'];

    protected $messages = [
        'post_title.required' => 'Introduceti titlul articolului',
        'post_title.unique' => 'Exista deja un asemenea titlu',
        'post_content.required' => 'Introduceti continutul articolului',
        'post_image.required' => 'Atasati o imagine articolului',
        'post_image.mimes' => 'Imaginea trebuie sa fie in format jpeg/png/jpg/gif/svg',
        'post_category.required' => 'Selectati categoria articolului',
    ];
    public function addNewPost(){
        dd($this);
            $this->validate();
            $post = Post::addNewPost($this);
            if(!$post){
                $this->showToastr('Articolul nu a putut fi adaugat','error');
            }
            $this->showToastr('Articolul a fost adaugat cu succes','success');
            $this->reset();


    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.posts');
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you link the script? could you edit and include in the question how the script is linked? (I mean how is it connected with te component view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have the script and the component view in separate files and that's why you get an error on `@this('post_content').set('post_content', e.editor.getData());` line.

According to the docs, both should be placed in the same file (component file), then `@this` will be available in the script (you can read more about that [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/inline-scripts#introduction))

***Example:*** let's assume you have a **form** component that will look like this:

```
<form>
<!-- your form elements -->
</form>

@push('scripts')
<script>
    // accessing @this here should work
</script>
@endpush
```

Hope it helps :)